# How can I plot the 1/x function with points?

Tags: graph, graphics, processing

I want to make the 1 / x function be formed by points, making a graph, with Processing, in a for loop.

```
size(400,400);

for(int x=1; x<100; x++){
  float y=1;
  y=1/x;
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(x,y);
}
```

The code should form a curve, but only generates a small line.

Answer (score 2):

Processing has graphics functions for basic drawing. You're using only a few pixels at the top left corner of your screen.

Try a graphics library like [gwoptics](http://www.gwoptics.org/processing/gwoptics_p5lib/) to plot a graph with conventionally oriented axes (Origin at bottom left).

Alternatively, scale you X and Y axis, and flip the Y.

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(100);

for(x=1; x<100; x++) {
  y=1/x;
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(x*4,400-400*y);
}
}
```

Tested on https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/create
[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code.
The first pixel is at (1, 1) because 1/1 is 1.
The second pixel is at (1, 0.5) etc.

This is probably not what you want.
If you actually want to see anything, multiply the y by some value:

```
point(x,100*y);
```

If you were to try this code, however, you will only see one separate point and the rest are still a line.

This is because at`y=1/x;` you are dividing by an integer. This is bad, because dividing by an integer will also return an integer. What you actually want is dividing by a float:

```
y=1/(float)x;  //This is called casting. It converts x to a float
```